# Ruby on Rails Devise Gem, specify email template from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a controller which inherited from ApplicationController
where I send reset password insturctions, is there any way to specify template?

```
@user=User.find_by_email(email);
if @user.nil?
  render :status=>404, :json=>{:message=>"User not found or email format is invalid."}
  return
else
  @user.devise_mailer.reset_password_instructions(@user).deliver
  render :status=>200, :json=>{:message=>"Reset password instructions have been sent."}
end
```

As you see in the snippet above,  @user.devise_mailer.reset_password_instructions(@user).deliver
Sends reset password instructions, but it takes default email template, which I don't wanna change. I need to create another template and somehow specify to use it

Answer (score 0):

Create your own mailer then. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html for details. Once you have a new mailer, in the controller, instead of:

```
@user.devise_mailer.reset_password_instructions(@user).deliver
```

you'd do something like:

```
YourMailer.reset_password_instructions(@user).deliver
```

You may want to reuse parts of Devise in your mailer: check out devise sources for that: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/mailers/helpers.rb

Another thing you may try is redefining devise template by putting a file named `app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb` in your application directory. Of course you can base your implementation on devise sources as well: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb